# What does it mean by vector fields are closed under Lie bracket?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, general-relativity

[image]

For (a), what does it mean by three vectors given are closed under Lie bracket? Does it mean that $[X,Y]=Z$ or something like this? But when I compute $[X,Y]$ , it is something messy and doesn't look like any one of $X,Y,Z\dots$Could anyone please explain?

Comment: From a first look, I'd say that the lie bracket of two would yield the other one left? Not sure about this.

Comment: It might be useful to say which book/lecture notes you have taken this from..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\frak{g}$ is your Lie Algebra, then showing closure here means exactly what you think, that is for any $X,Y \in \frak{g}$ we must have $[X,Y] \in \frak{g}$

This is a bit long, but you have to use the bilinearity of the bracket

\begin{align*}
[X,Y ] &= [-\sin\phi \partial_\theta - \cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\phi, \cos \phi \partial_\theta - \cot\theta \sin\phi \partial_\phi] \\
&= [-\sin\phi \partial_\theta, \cos \phi \partial_\theta - \cot\theta \sin\phi \partial_\phi] + [- \cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\phi, \cos \phi \partial_\theta - \cot\theta \sin\phi \partial_\phi]\\
&=[-\sin\phi \partial_\theta, \cos \phi \partial_\theta]+ [ -\sin\phi \partial_\theta, - \cot\theta \sin\phi \partial_\phi] + [- \cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\phi, \cos \phi \partial_\theta] + [- \cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\phi, - \cot\theta \sin\phi \partial_\phi]\\
&=-\frac{-\sin^2\phi}{\sin^2\theta}\partial_\phi - \sin\phi\cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\theta + \sin\phi\cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\theta - \frac{\cos^2\phi}{\sin^2\theta} \partial_\phi + \cot^2\theta \partial_\phi\\
&=\partial_\phi\\
&=Z\\
[X,Z] &= [-\sin\phi \partial_\theta - \cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\phi,  \partial_\phi] \\
&=[-\sin\phi \partial_\theta,\partial_\phi] + [- \cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\phi,  \partial_\phi]\\
&=\cos\phi \partial_\phi - \sin\phi \cot\theta \partial_\phi \\
&=Y\\
[Y,Z ] &= [ \cos \phi \partial_\theta - \cot\theta \sin\phi \partial_\phi,  \partial_\phi] \\
&=[\cos \phi \partial_\theta,\partial_\phi] + [- \cot\theta \sin\phi \partial_\phi,  \partial_\phi]\\
&=-\sin\phi \partial_\theta - \cos\phi\cot\theta \partial_\phi\\
&=X
\end{align*}